# Why do we explicitly overwrite the next pointer to None when its original node attribute sets it to None by default in SLL?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am picking up linked lists in python. Basically I'm writing a logic for adding a node ***at the front of my linked list***.
But, my teacher did it a little different and so I need to understand why there is a need for the following piece of line.

**Here is the entire code for reference.**

```
#Singly linked list in Python3
class SLLNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self): 
        return "SLLNode object data = {}".format(self.data)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data


    def set_data(self, new_data):
        self.data= new_data


    def get_next(self):
        return self.next


    def set_next(self, new_next):
        self.next= new_next

#Singly Linked List class
class SLL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head= None

    def __repr__(self):
        return "SLL object head: {}".format(self.head)

    def isempty(self): 
        return self.head is None 

    def add_front(self, new_data):
        temp = SLLNode(new_data)
        temp.set_next(self.head)  # Why do we need this line?
        self.head= temp
```

So in the `add_front` method of `SLL` class, why do we need to go through setting `set_next=None` by doing this

```
 temp = SLLNode(new_data)
 temp.set_next(self.head)  
 self.head= temp
```

When I see the next pointer is being set to `None` by default in the `SLLNode` class.And so I do this and get the same output.

```
 temp = SLLNode(new_data)
 self.head= temp
```

Is it some case I am missing on in here that my teacher did not explain? Or my program will do fine without that extra line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is true if you only ever call `add_front` once.

But the second time you call `add_front`, `self.head` is no longer `None`, and actually points to the previous head.

To visualize, this is what happens the first time you call `add_front`:

```
Before: None
After: A -> None
```

You create a new node (which we'll call  A) and make it point to the previous head, which is None. But the second time this happens:

```
Before: A -> None
After: B -> A -> None
```

We create another node (B), and make it point to the previous head. But now the previous head is no longer None, it is A!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused here when you did it with B. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I understood and accept ***orlp's*** answer, I would like to clarify it by breaking it down into a much simpler sentence.

Basically, our `self.head` can point to `None` or a ***linked list with nodes***.
Now, if latter is the case we cannot insert our new node simply by doing

```
temp = SLLNode(new_data)
self.head= temp
```

This is basically creating a node with a value in it and makes the `self.head` points to it. But while doing this, we break the link to the other chain of already present linked list to which our `self.head` was pointing to before.

So to systematically summarize,

***Step 1 :*** We initialize our new/`temp` node.

```
temp=SLLNode(new_data)
```

Here we just make a node and initialize it with a value. the `self.next` pointer will be None at this time.

***Step 2 :*** We make out newly initialized node point to the same place where the `self.head` is currently pointing to.(It could be pointing to `None` or a node. So if `None` is the case then my logic of commenting out `temp.set_next(self.head)` works but if its pointing to a node then my logic breaks the connection to the existing chain and `self.Head` now points to the `temp`/ newly created node only, which is wrong because by doing this we have broken the connection to existing chain. That's the reason why we do the below piece of code.It ensures that my newly created node/`temp` also points to the same place where `self.head` does and so now even if we break the connection of `self.head` we  have our chain of linked list secure.)

```
temp.set_next(self.head)
```

***Step 3 :*** Now we just make the `self.head` point to the `temp`/newly created pointer, so that we have a complete chain.

```
self.head= temp
```

*Just a side note* - I found it a bit confusing in the beginning and I don't want others to weather that discomfort when they have this confusion which is why my  steps are purposefully collaborative.
Hope it helps :)